# Plot US map in R without Alaska and Hawaii

Tags: r, plot

Anyone knows how can I plot a US map in R without the states of Alaska and Hawaii?

I have tried with `plot_usmap` and `ggplot2`, but I can't remove those states from the plot.

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the xlim and ylim through coord_map() or coord_cartesian() in ggplot2? You should be able to zoom just into the continental US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exclude` argument in `plot_usmap`:

```r
library(usmap)
plot_usmap(data = statepop, values = "pop_2015",
           exclude = c("AK","HI"))

# Without any fillings:
plot_usmap(exclude = c("AK","HI"))
```

[image]

Using `ggplot2`, you can directly load the US states by doing:

```r
library(ggplot2)

us <- map_data("state")
ggplot()+
  geom_map(data = us, map = us, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id=region))
```

[image]